# Getting error "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Chrome'"

Tags: python, webdriver

I have written my first python script using selenium. I am using pycharm.
I got an error of chrome driver even I have downloaded chrome driver & set path in my script.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome ("C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")
driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
driver.get("http://www.facebook.com")
driver.maximazie_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
driver.get_screenshot_as_file("Facebook.png")
driver.quit()
```

I got an error like this

```
C:\Users\SapanaD\PycharmProjects\seleniumscripts\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/SapanaD/PycharmProjects/seleniumscripts/facebookpackage/Myfirstscript.py
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:/Users/SapanaD/PycharmProjects/seleniumscripts/facebookpackage/Myfirstscript.py",
>   line 4, in 
>           driver = webdriver.Chrome ("C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")
>       AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Chrome'
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

I have tried double backslace"\" & install chrome driver also. I have research so many things but I cannot get proper solution.

Comment: Do you have a space between webdriver.Chrome and ("C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")? If yes try removing the space.

Comment: space does not matter @ForFunAndProfit

Comment: No, there is no space between webdriver.Chrome

Comment: @sapana, i am able to use your code without any errors

Comment: may be use this driver = webdriver.Chrome (r"C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")

Comment: add r infront of the location string

Comment: Tried just now but not working.

Comment: Is this chrome browser version issue? Which selenium  version have you used ?

Comment: The same code is working on eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Copy chromedriver.exe file in C:\Python27 location and after that try like as below and also if import statement is wrong then above exception will get

````
from selenium import webdriver

# create a new Firefox session
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.maximize_window()

# Navigate to the application home page
driver.get("http://www.google.com")

# close the browser window
driver.quit() ```
````